# Redirect web traffic to local server

Tags: linux, iptables

I saw this pair of commands:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.42.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
```

How can I change that to redirect all the web traffic to 192.168.1.65 on port 43594?

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.65:43594
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.65:43594
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a transparent proxy.
Check [this manual](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-6.html), if it so. First of all you need to accept connection to you port:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.65 -i eth0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 43594 -j ACCEPT
```

Next step, is to modify network table for routing all traffic from and out correctly:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s ! 192.168.1.65 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.65:43594
```

NOTE: this line you are provided:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

is for [routing traffic](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)